# Ajax refusing to fetch server time

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I've been following an example in an Ajax book I've been reading.

I have put together the code as instructed. The idea is to fetch the php server time and display it when a button is clicked.

The publication was 2006 and I'm unsure if anything I have written is outdated and perhaps not supported anymore causing it to break?

I would be grateful for any guidance, thanks!

AJAX page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax Demonstration</title>
    <style>
        .displaybox{
            width: 150px;
            margin:0 auto;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 2px solid #000;
            padding: 10px;
            font:24px normal verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function getXMLHTTPRequest(){
            try{
                reg = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch(err1){
                try{
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Msxm12.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(err2){
                    try{
                        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch(err3){
                        req = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var http = getXMLHTTPRequest();

        function getServerTime(){
            var myurl = 'telltimeXML.php';
            myRand = parseInt(Math.random()* 999999999999999);
            //add random number to URL to avoid cache problems
            var modurl = myurl+"?rand="+myRand;
            http.open("GET", modurl, true);
            //set up the callback function
            http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
            http.send(null);
        }

        function useHttpResponse(){
            if(http.readyState == 4){
                if(http.status == 200){
                    var timeValue = http.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("timenow")[0];
                    document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = timeValue.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                }
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = '<img src="anim.gif">';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#ccc; text-align:center" onLoad="getServerTime()">
    <h1>Ajax Demonstration</h1>
    <h2>Getting the server time without page refresh</h2>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Get Server Time" onClick="getServerTime()" />
    </form>
    <div id="showtime" class="displaybox"></div>
</body>
```

PHP page

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?><clock1><timenow>".date('H:i:s')."</timenow></clock1>";
?>
```

Comment: Check your browser's dev tools for errors -- especially the "Console" and "Network." Also, are both files served over HTTP/HTTPS and within the same directory path?

Comment: All files are in the same directory for simplicity. This is the error the console is logging > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'open' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
var http = getXMLHTTPRequest();
```

is expecting that `getXMLHttpRequest()` will `return` the instance. However, the `function` is instead attempting to directly set `req`:

```
// ...

req = new XMLHttpRequest();

// ...
```

Probably the simplest solution would be to change each `req =` to `return`:

```
function getXMLHTTPRequest(){
    try{
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(err1){
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Though, you could also declare `http` sooner and set it directly instead:

```
var http;

function getXMLHTTPRequest(){
    try{
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(err1){
        // etc.
    }
}

getXMLHttpRequest(); // no need for `http =` here, since they're in the function
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, madness that the book had me doing something that didn't make sense. Using the information you provided, I now understand what is going on and changed it in both ways to get the same outcome. Simple but it works! Thanks bud.